# Suggestions for fog?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders

So i have been working on this scene for a while using cycles and wanted to have a fog with a shape like in the image, the problem is that it looks too cheap, cut out and i cannot think of anything to make it look better, any help? (i took screenshots so thats why the render looks grainy)

[image]

Below is my node set up for the fog inside the mesh

[image]

thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want these curvy shapes you can try **Volume Empty** object with two volume modifiers.

- Add a *Cube*, switch to *Sculpt* mode and with enabled **Dyntopo** use **Snake Hook** tool
- Add **Volume > Empty** object
- Add modifier **Mesh to Volume** and use the *Cube* as *Object*
- Alternatively for more distortion you can use **Volume Displace** modifier with *Cloud* texture

Sculpted - three drags with *Snake Hook* tool (screen from edit mode)
[image]

*Volume > Empty* object with *Mesh to Volume* modifier
[image]

Added *Volume Displace* modifier > *Cloud* texture
[image]

... another example smaller size texture and higher *Density* set in shader
[image]

Volume modifier available from Blender 2.92 and above ... I'm so big fan of this feature.
Just a few clicks :)

BTW - ad to "graine" render - in Properties editor under Render property >Sampling > Denoising enable Viewport / Render Screens above are just result of 4 samples :)

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant! thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

If you want the most realistic result, you should consider using a smoke simulation. However, if you want to do it using a shader, you can try something like this. The object I used is a plane, placed in front of the scene.

[image: Fog1]

All I did to make it was to warp the vectors of a Noise Texture with another Noise Texture  (to make it even more random and "whispy") using a Vector Math node. The MixRGB in the middle is to lessen the warp effect.

[image: Fog2]

Then I used the same warped vector combined with a Gradient Texture and a ColorRamp to make an alpha mask.

[image: Fog3]

I show it in the photo (but not connected) that I also combined (multiplied) the original Noise Texture that I used for the warp factor (through another ColorRamp) with my alpha mask to make more "holes" in it.

The end result looks like this. Don't forget to put a light in front of it to make it show up:

[image: Fog4]

Answer (score 1):

You could create a cube, give it this node setup, which is a mix between a *Noise Texture* and a *Gradient* through a *Math (Multiply)*, the *Gradient* making the *Noise* fade out on the Z axis:

[image]

Here is what it gives:

[image]

Front view:

[image]

Or you could try to improve your solution:

- Create your cloud object with metaballs, keep the *Resolution* low to make them smooth. When you're glad with your shape, select them all and in the header menu > *Object > Convert to > Mesh*:

[image]

- Create your material, plug the *Principled Volume* into the *Volume* socket of the *Material Output*. Plug a *Noise Texture* into the *Density* socket of the *Principled Volume*. As this setup won't take the cloud shape into account (the cut out aspect), plug a mix between *Transparent* and *Diffuse* into the Surface socket of the *Material Output* with a *Layer Weight* as factor:

[image]

- Here is what it gives (I've added two *Point* lights in order to make it a bit brighter, but you could also add an *Emission* shader in your node setup, or give your *Principled Volume* a bit of *Emission Strength*):

[image]