# How To Make Volumetrics Round?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine, lighting, volumetrics

I'm currently working on a spaceship render. The engines glow and emit light. I have cubes behind each thruster that contain volumetric properties, I want these to look like a subtle back burner or just some ambient light coming out from the thrusters.

As you can imagine, the engine thrusters are circular. I have my volumetric in a cube, and of course the gas is cubic. It is not the right shape I am trying to accomplish. I need the volume circular, or just soften edges.

I have attached an image of the render, with the problem of the square volumetric occurring, as well as a screenshot of the nodes I used for the volumetric shader.

[image: shaderspaceship]

Comment: volumetrics will be cubic in Eevee, but you could use a Volume > Empty with a Mesh to Volume modifier and a Dsiplace modifier as explained here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201071/suggestions-for-fog

Comment: or use this kind of trick: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/204710/how-can-i-make-a-light-trail-without-using-particles/204745#204745

Answer (score 5):

You could just consider the box to be a vector space in which you can sculpt your flame, by making its [ density | emission strength | color ] a function of the box's X,Y and Z.

Keeping it simple, here .. This box measures 2x2x4 Blender Units with its origin in the center of its base, and X,Y, and Z are measured in Object space.

[image]

- (Left) By setting the density to 1 - the XYZ length, you get a hemisphere:

[image]

- (Center) You could scale the Z to get an ellipsoid:

[image]

- (Right) You could split the Z off as a multiplier, and sculpt it with a curve:

[image]

Of course you could extend this principle to vary colors, get flames-within-flames, etc. etc.

[image]

Comment: ..oops, I left the file in Cycles.. but it works fine in EEVEE..

Answer (score 1):

If you start with a UV sphere as your "volume object", you can constrain the volume using a (scaled & clamped) Spherical Gradient (Gradient Texture), as a Mix Factor between the Volume and a Transparent Shader.

[image: Sphere]

Comment: Why so complicated? There's no need for a _Transparent Shader_ and a _Mix Shader_, this is no surface material.... just plug the output of the _Color Ramp_ into the density of the _Volume Scatter Node_. Wherever it is black, the density is 0 (= transparent). If the density is too low or too high, put a _Math Node_ set to _Multiply_ between _Color Ramp_ and _Volume Scatter_. Apart from that, the answer provided by Robin Betts works much better for your purposes because you don't have shape the bounding object for the engine shape.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea I tried out for you really quickly.  Didn't get great results, but didn't try long so you may be able to get it to work.  If you:

1. Make the volumetric shape emit particles (maybe creating some internal geometry so that it emits particles inside the object)
2. Create a small sphere object that has the volumetric material
3. Make the particle system emit this object.

Still gives kind of a pixelated look as all the little objects are still cube volumes, so may not work.